# Angular: how to change image in a specific row of table created by *ngFor loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So, I have a generated by ngFor table.
In each row I have button with image as background:

```
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let movie of movies let i = index'>
        <td>...some values here...</td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <button name="watchLater_butom">
              <img [src]='watchLaterIcon' alt="icon (click)='AddToWatchLater(i)'> 
            </button>
          </span>
       </td>
    </tbody>
```

And my component:

```
export class MyComponent{
    watchLaterIcon: string = '/assets/watchLater_icon.png';
    emptyWatchLaterIcon: string = '/assets/emptyWatchLater_icon.png';

    AddToWatchLater(i : number) : void {
        var tempWatchLaterIcon = this.watchLaterIcon;
        this.watchLaterIcon = this.emptyWatchLaterIcon;
        this.emptyWatchLaterIcon = tempWatchLaterIcon;
    }
}
```

By now, all the images are changed by clicking any button. What I need is to change only one image src for a button which I clicked.

I suppose it has to be done something in `AddToWatchLater()` method. I guess, that it might work via index of row which I pass to the method, but have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .ts file, firstly create a new array, each element of this array is going to have watchLaterIcon string, and its length should be the same as the movies array, so add a for loop in the constructor:

```
imageSources: string[] = [];

constructor() 
{  
   for(let i=0; i<this.movies.length; i++)
   {
      this.imageSources[i] = watchLaterIcon;
   }
}
```

Then make a new component for the button 'ButtonComponent', and edit your .html file so the ngFor iterates through button component and pass in image sources as inputs to the component:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let imageSource of imageSources>
            <td>...some values here...</td>
            <td>
                <span>
                  <app-button [inputImageSrc]="imageSource"><app-button>    
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

**Button component .HTML file:**

```
<button (click)="getSelected()">
  <img src={{imgSrc}} alt="icon"> 
</button>
```

**Button component .Ts file:**

```
emptyWatchLaterIcon: string = '/assets/emptyWatchLater_icon.png';

@Input('inputImageSrc') imgSrc: string; // get input and use as 'src' in the img tag

getSelected() // Change the image source, applies only to the clicked button of the ngFor loop.
{
  this.imgSrc = emptyWatchLaterIcon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change dynamically depending of the position of the array data managing it in object per movie, a quick example:

Ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  watchLaterIcon: string = 'https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/action/watch_later_black_192x192.png';
  emptyWatchLaterIcon: string = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT53nVsfr2bXkVsrEZ8Mjsbwk4-dQzfPL1XuVWNPVy5Ex52AQAM';
  movies:{} = [{ name: 'Movie 1' }, { name: 'Movie 2' }]
  AddToWatchLater(index){
    const actualsrc = this.movies[index].src;
    if(actualsrc){
      this.movies[index].src = actualsrc === this.watchLaterIcon ? this.emptyWatchLaterIcon : this.watchLaterIcon;
    }else {
      this.movies[index].src = this.emptyWatchLaterIcon;
    }
  }
}
```

Html file :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let movie of movies let i = index'>
            <td>...some values here...</td>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <button name="watchLater_butom">
                        <img [src]="movie.src ? movie.src : watchLaterIcon" alt="icon" (click)="AddToWatchLater(i)" > 
                    </button>
                  </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but `scr` it is not a property of movie. It's an attribute of `<img>`. How did you call src on object's from the loop?

Comment: Yes it is part of the src attributes but to be added dynamically you just added to the movie property to know its context